# Identify this book. Two stories taking place at once, alternating by chapter

Tags: story-identification, horror, crime

This book told two stories at the same time, alternating by chapter.

One was a violent detective thriller set in Northern Ireland around the 90s and the other was a horror / mystery taking place from the point of view of the author of the crime thriller as (s)he writes it.

The author in the story is writing the crime thriller and as (s)he completes each chapter, more sinister events start taking place around their home as they are terrorised by ghosts, apparitions and eventually demons. I can't remember any of the events specifically but I remember by the end you're pretty nervous and freaked out for the author. I'm pretty sure Satan makes an appearance or at least some deal with the devil is implied on the part of the author.

I'm assuming the author of the entire book is from the UK or Ireland because the detective story takes place in NI, but I could be mistaken.

It's a great book overall, it's definitely an adult's book due to the language and violence.

I read this probably 7 - 10 years ago.

Comment: Can you tell when you read this book, and maybe when it was published?

Comment: @b_jonas I read it probably 7 - 10 years ago. I couldn't say when it was published I'm afraid. Probably around the same time but I can't be sure.

Comment: Did either of these have a SF/F angle to them? Nothing in your question sounds like it.

Comment: @phantom42 The author is haunted and terrorised by ghosts and demons for the majority of the book. So horror/fantasy, does that count?

Comment: @Daft works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it, [Hybrid](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1483427.Hybrid) by Shaun Hutson.

Pretty mixed reviews... I remember it being great!

[image]

Comment: Congrats. Always nice when you find what you're looking for.